# Writing JPEG from HttpResponse to file in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpresponse, outputstream

I am having trouble writing a .jpg file from an http server to the filesystem of an android device. I use this code:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

public void processResult(HttpResponse response) {

    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 401){

        if(response != null){
            File file = new File(parent, myLocation);
            try {
               file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
               file.createNewFile();
               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               FileOutputStream fileOS  = new FileOutputStream(file);
               entity.writeTo(fileOS);
               entity.consumeContent();
               fileOS.flush();
               fileOS.close();
               success  =   true;
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

The jpg file is 73369 bytes. If I stop the debugger on the success = true line, I can see entity.getContentLength() to be 73369, which is correct. However, file.length() gives me 0 most of the time, and sometimes 7770 or some size somewhere in between.

If I check on the Android device on the file explorer it shows length of 7 KB or less.

I tried other ways in handling the InputStream, but none to success:

I tried getting a byte array and writing that to a file, but this gives me an empty byte array:

```
private static void writeToFile(File file, byte[] bs) throws IOException{
       file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
       file.createNewFile();

       FileOutputStream fileOS  = new FileOutputStream(file);
       fileOS.write(bs);
       fileOS.flush();
       fileOS.close();
}
```

I started trying to write the input stream to a file, but this gave the same result

```
public static final void streamToFile(File file, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
   file.createNewFile();

   FileOutputStream fileOS  = new FileOutputStream(file);

   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bytesRead;      

   while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
       fileOS.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    stream.close();
    fileOS.flush();
    fileOS.close();
}
```

The inputstream seems fine, but I cannot get it into a file. Anybody a helping hand on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code shown above is correct. Problem was that the connection was closed before reading the stream was finished. Overlooked that because get requests for string (JSON) were fine (small response size).